# How do I declare a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I was creating a program to work with a drop-down list, but I got stuck at the line of declaration of JComboBox box, I get these error messages: 
  Multiple markers at this line
    - The constructor JComboBox(String[]) is 
     undefined
    - Line breakpoint:JComboBox [line: 25] - 
     JComboBox()
  No matter how I try to define JComboBox, I get some sort of error. Please help me with it.

Here's the code of the public class:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
    import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

    public class JComboBox extends JFrame {

        private JComboBox box;
        private JLabel picture;

        private static String[] filename = { "p.png", "i.png" };
        private Icon pics[] = { new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0])),
                new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[1])) };

        public JComboBox() {

            super("This is the title");
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            JComboBox box = new JComboBox(filename);

            box.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                    if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                        picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
                    }
                }
            });

            add(box);
            picture = new JLabel(pics[0]);
            add(picture);

        }

    }
```

And here's the code of the main class:

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class JComboBox1 extends JFrame {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            JComboBox Box = new JComboBox();
            Box.setVisible(true);
            Box.setSize(400,400);
            Box.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have nameclash with existing Swing class [javax.swing.JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html), which you've imported with `import javax.swing.*`. Try changing the class name.

Comment: Thank you! It fixed my problem. I should have known better, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, as @Andy mentioned is that you have a collision in the name of your class and the swing component.  If you absolutely must name your class JComboBox you'll have to reference the swing component by the fully-qualified name, as such

```
public class JComboBox extends JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JComboBox box;
```

If you hover over your private instance with an IDE you should see the fully-qualified name matching the package in which you've created your JComboBox class.  Save yourself some pain and rename your class.

Comment: I'm guessing this is insufficient. Likely would need to get rid of `import javax.swing.*` as well. The best answer is *don't do that.* Don't name a class exactly the same as a standard library class. Avoid even using the prefix Swing uses to distinguish its classes. It's confusing, and will cost you time and grief.

Comment: I always prefer to be explicit with imports, but that's just my preference.  The above was just to provide a bit more insight into what's going on, but yes, I agree with you in that _don't do that_ is the best answer. :)

Comment: I managed to fix it just by renaming the class. I should have known better, this mistake is as novice as it gets. Thank you all!

Comment: I apologize for not giving you a badge "I accept this answer". I made sure I did now. Thank you again for all the help! Have a great day! :)